# Join images with padding and alignment

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick

I have two images of different height which I want to join horizontally (i.e. side-by-side). I want the images to be bottom-aligned as well as to be separated by a 25 pixel wide white area.

With `montage` I managed to get both effects separately but using them together eliminates the alignment specification:

```
montage [1-2].png -tile 2x1 -gravity south out.png  # correctly aligns at bottom
montage [1-2].png -tile 2x1 -geometry +25+0 out.png  # correctly adds padding
```

Using `-gravity south -geometry +25+0` eliminates the alignment effect.

With `convert +append -gravity south [1-2].png out.png` I can similarly bottom-align the images but I don't know how to add the padding.

Is there a way to apply both effects simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a small white image between the two images you want to append :

```
convert [1-2].png -size 25x0 xc:White +swap -background White \
        -gravity South +append  OUT.png
```

More examples: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16383